# How to execute one PHP file inside the move uploaded file

Tags: php

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['CSV_fileupload']['tmp_name'], $filetarget_path))
    {
       include 'web_csv.php?fname='.basename( $_FILES['CSV_fileupload']['name']).'';
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['CSV_fileupload']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded";


    }
```

I want to execute the uploaded file in web_csv.php

Need to pass like this
web_csv.php?fname='basename( $_FILES['CSV_fileupload']['name'])';

Comment: what do you mean "execute this csv file"? Does it contain some executable command and you want it to be executed?

Comment: A CSV cannot be "executed". A local PHP file shouldn't be `include`d via URLs. There's so much wrong here it's hard to know what you actually want.

Comment: Guys, he didn't say `execute csv file`. He said `execute PHP file`

Comment: @Oleg Quote: *"I want to execute this csv file in server side"*

Comment: @deceze, you perhaps didn't see the question Title. OP just had difficulties putting it together. Get familiar with Indian English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your `web_csv.php` expects `GET` parameter `"fname"`.
Try this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['CSV_fileupload']['tmp_name'], $filetarget_path))
{
   echo "The file ".basename($_FILES['CSV_fileupload']['name'])." has been uploaded";
   $_GET['fname'] = basename( $filetarget_path ); // or just $filetarget_path ?
   include 'web_csv.php';
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. I'm thinking that the OP wants to be able to do processing on the cvs (just bad wording, not executing the cvs). Thus, he wants to run `web_csv` with GET variables. This code does exactly that. You might want to change it to `$_GET['fname'] = basename($filetarget_path);` though.

Comment: Who knows. At least giving OP an idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. upload file and move the file with `move_uploaded_file`
2. if `move_uploaded_file` function return `true` redirect to your `csv_processor.php` or whatever is called.
3. find scripts / tutorial out there how to read csv file. CSV is **comma separated value**, so basically you only need explode by `\n` to convert each line as array and `,` to convert each columns of lines as array. just use it magic keyword `how to read csv file with php` in google for detail.
4. remove the temporary csv file.